# Why do Chinese Consulate Generals use @gmail.com email addresses, rather than official ones?

Tags: china

I hope I am not being phished or spoofed? If these are the legitimate websites of the Chinese Consulates, why would they use @gmail.com? Why don't they use their official addresses ending in gov.cn?

On the left side of http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/

> E-mail: chinaembpress_us@mfa.gov.cn

But on the right side

> Email for Authentication Application: authenticationoffice.dc@gmail.com

http://newyork.chineseconsulate.org/eng/tzgg/t1860769.htm

> II. The newly added email address visaoffice.ny@gmail.com will be for inquiries related to Chinese Visa, Notarization/Authentication.

http://newyork.china-consulate.org/eng/zjfw/lxwm/201503/t20150304_5520170.htm

> Email: cnnyconsulate@gmail.com

http://www.chinaconsulatechicago.org/eng/lgxx/gywm/200711/t20071106_5496383.htm

> Email: chineseconsulgeneral.chicago@gmail.com

Scroll to the bottom.

> Temporary Closure during the COVID-19 outbreak
>
> Applicants are advised to postpone all applications.
>
> Fax: 312-453-0211
>
> Email: chinavisachicago@gmail.com

Comment: You might get a better answer in the travel or Expatriates exchanges

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a question about politics and political processes [as defined in the help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). And even if it were on-topic, we probably could not answer it without going into wild speculation.

Comment: Just a guess that it's easier for them to set up gmail accounts than request their MFA to set up various sub-accounts. Bureaucracy and all that. A quick google search for "consulates using gmail" finds some from other countries doing the same.

Comment: @Fizz Irony being, Gmail services are blocked in China by the government.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: When in Rome...

Comment: This is such a quirky & interesting question, and I think it can be made on-topic and potentially reopened. Instead of "Why do...?" which can't be fact-based-answered very easily, perhaps you can change to "How far does the "Great Firewall" reach? Does the use of gmail for official correspondence by people working within the grounds of official Chinese embassies in any way conflict with Chinese government's blocking Chinese citizens from using it in China?" The idea being that the inside of an official embassy is pretty close to but not the same as being inside the country itself in some ways.

Comment: @uhoh Don't hesitate to edit my question, to make it on topic!

Comment: @asts I think it will be a good exercise but I'm not the right person to do it. Go for it!